# Is there any way to load custom angular.json in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

We are migrating our apps into the micro frontend.
I need to have different workspace configurations for the single spa and normal app.

> Is there any way to load angular-spa.json file while ng serve?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use [NX](https://nx.dev)?